# Javascript function to show div with php content only flashes up

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've written a javascript function to show a PHP within a Div. It seems to work, except that the php to be shown only flashes up for a brief second. Is there any way to get it to stay shown until I select an option to close it.

Many thanks

```
    function showBiog(keysop){
$.ajax({
                url: 'test2.php?number=' + keysop,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $('#SubmitForm').serialize(),
                success: function(content)
                {
                    $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
                }  
        });
        event.preventDefault();
$('#submit_btn_id').click();
}
```

Comment: Add a console.log() call to your success function to see if it is called twice for some reason. There is nothing in your code that would explain the "flashing" of the result, unless it is overwritten almost immediately by a second call.

Comment: thanks, repaired it within the form myself.

Comment: what is `$('#submit_btn_id').click();` for??